# Umbraco cache issue - front end not refreshing immediately

Tags: umbraco, umbraco6

I have Umbraco CMS Version (Umbraco v6.1.6 (Assembly version: 1.0.5021.24867)).
I have a strange issue, whenever I make any change in back-end using **editContent.aspx** page, it some times reflect on front end immediately, but most of time it doesn't reflect on front end.

Then I use "Republish entire site", this works on Production but not on my local environment. I have checked **umbraco.config** file in **App_Data** folder. And it contains the changes immediately, when i save in back-end.

But I studied some where that touching web.config reflects the changes immediately, and this works in my case.

But this is very annoying solution, for both Production & local environment.

Even if I need to use "Republish entire site" all the time I save any back-end content on Production is very frustrating.

Note: I searched a lot about this, but no solution worked for me.

Thanks

Comment: What does your log say? Does it have any errors?